# Why is my data being replicated three times when inserting data into database throught a php/html form?

Tags: php

I'm trying to just insert data into the html/php form and then that new data is displayed on the php/html table on the same page, however when I insert the data it is returned 3 times or so. why is this? Here is pic of whats being output in firefox.

[The result when inserting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYPNQ.png)

This is my index.php file

```
<?php
    // this is the connection to the database
    include_once "includes/connection.php";
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <?php
            //this selects the different columns from the different tables and then queries them.
            $sql = "SELECT test3.speed, test2.model, test1.car FROM test1, test2, test3 ";
            $result = $conn-> query($sql);


                echo "<table>
                <tr>
                <th>Car</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Speed</th>
                </tr>";

                //output the data of each row

               while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                   echo "<tr>
                   <td>" . $row["car"] . "</td>
                   <td>" . $row["model"] . "</td>
                   <td>" . $row["speed"] . "</td>
                   </tr>";
               }
            echo "</table>";

            // This form "SHOULD" insets data into tables "test1", "test2", "test3"
        ?>
        <form action="includes/register.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="car" placeholder="Car">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="model">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="speed" placeholder="speed">
            <br>
            <button action="submit" name="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my register.php file

```
<?php
    include_once "connection.php";

    $car = $_POST['car'];
    $model = $_POST['model'];
    $speed = $_POST['speed'];

    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO test1 (car) VALUES ('$car')");
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO test3 (speed) VALUES ('$speed')");
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO test2 (model) VALUES ('$model')");

    if ($conn)  
    { 
        echo "successful"; 
    } 
    else  
    { 
        echo "Error"; 
    } 

        header ("Location: ../index.php?register=success");
```

I found no working way of drawing the tables to you so it would be easy to see so here is what they consist of

**test1** (table1)

- Idtest1 is primary key with auto-increase
- Car is just a normal varchar(45)

**test2** (table2)

- Idtest2 is primary key with auto-increase
- Model is just a normal varchar(45)

**test3** (table3)

- Idtest3 is primary key with auto-increase
- Speed is just a normal varchar(45)

I can for the life of me figure out why its outputting data multiple times instead of just once when I'm inserting new data through the form. I have tried using `WHERE`, but this just prevents the table from updating once I hit the button. I'm also quite new to php so any tips would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Because you run that on every page load

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have an idea how to join your data, so it's just prints all of it.
The first thing you should do is to create associations columns in your tables.

Based on your needs, I think following example will suit:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `car` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `model` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `car_id` INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `speed` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `car_id` INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
INSERT INTO car(`value`) VALUES ('audi');
INSERT INTO model(`value`,`car_id`) VALUES ('some_model',1);
INSERT INTO speed(`value`,`car_id`) VALUES ('some_speed',1);

INSERT INTO car(`value`) VALUES ('toyota');
INSERT INTO model(`value`,`car_id`) VALUES ('some_model2',2);
INSERT INTO speed(`value`,`car_id`) VALUES ('some_speed2',2);
```

Following schema lets you associate speed/model with you car, so you can just do some `JOIN` and get the result you need.

```
SELECT car.id,model.value,speed.value FROM car LEFT JOIN model on car.id=model.car_id LEFT JOIN speed ON car.id=speed.car_id;
```

[You can check out full example here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6746b5/1)

Comment: i tried adding the associations columns car_id and then change the $sql query so it looks like this ```SELECT test1.id, test1.car, test2.model, test3.speed FROM test1 LEFT JOIN test2 ON test1.id=test2.car_id LEFT JOIN test3 ON test1.id=test3.car_id```  but now it only displays the information from table1(test1) and none of the other tables.

Comment: @mago040402 Probably you're missing car_id at other tables. Its hard to say without your tables schema. Check that your tables definition corresponds to provided example.

Comment: car_id is located in test2(table2) and test3(table3) as belongs to primarykey and not null.

Comment: i also created a exact copy of the databse and tables you created however not the table wont update when data is inserted  EDIT: fixed that issue, however now im back to square one with the same issue. It only updates the values from Car table...

Comment: @mago040402 Show the query you use to update values.

Comment: My register.php has the insert queries and im using POST to get the data. I type something into the form when i want new data into the database

Comment: @mago040402 Providee register.php does not contain correct insert queries, as you should to also insert car_id of your car.